# Image Name binding not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am displaying a list of files like this:

```
<Image Name="{Binding fileId}" Source="/Assets/icons/add.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Tap="Image_Tap">
```

I am trying to fetch fileId value on image Tap event. but its giving exception `{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the name property, assign fileId to the Tag property and retrieve that on tap.

```
<Image Tag="{Binding fileId}" Source="/Assets/icons/add.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Tap="Image_Tap">
```

Of course, if you are binding a collection, you're probably going to be using a GridView or ListView control with a bound ItemsSource.  In that case, you can get the full object to which the individual element is bound by accessing the DataContext for the image.

```
Image myTappedImage = (Image)sender;
MyImgInfo mySourceObject = (MyImgInfo)(myTappedImage.DataContext);
```

Comment: Thanks, still I am not sure why NAME binding is not working. Its strange.